# textbox and richtextbox in c#

Tags: c#, textbox, numbers

I want when i write number in textbox
for example:
I write number four in textbox and then click button
in richtextbox I have four "A" (AAAA)
Whwn write number 6
in richtextbox I have six "A" (AAAAAA)

Comment: Have you tried to write this yourself already? If so post the code and where you are stuck

Comment: even if this is homework you should have a go at it

Comment: for (int b = 0; b < Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); b++)
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text += "A";
                   
                }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();    
for(int i = 0 i < int.Parse(textBox.Text); i++)
{
    sb.Append("A");
}
rtb.Text = sb.ToString()
```

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); i++)
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text += "A";
                   
                }